# Materialized view log of other schema

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have two tables in two different schemas
SCHEME A (tbl1)
SCHEME B (tbl2)

I created a materialized view that joins the two tables.

I would like to fast update and for that reason I have created two logs (one per table) using the rowi([ORA-12015 Cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141986/ora-12015-cannot-create-a-fast-refresh-materialized-view-from-a-complex-query))

When I create the view it tells me it's not possible as the query is complex. Actually the problem is the schema. Indeed the same query works if I create the tbl2 under the schema a. How to fix?

Comment: Make sure the schema that owns the materialized view also has select privileges on all source tables *and* materialized view logs.

Comment: Grants is ok for table and log

Comment: Run DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW to get more diagnostics about what is missing

Comment: I can't beacause DBA don't enabled it

Comment: How are the grants to the table and log in Schema B given? Are they direct object-level grants made to Schema A, or are they made through a role?

Comment: All grants given direcly to Schema A.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the classic Joins, it is sufficient to insert all the tables in the from and the join constraints in the where of the query